# Inconsistent boolean evaluation with "x is true" in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boolean-expression

Using Amazon Redshift. I have a boolean field that has 3 distinct values - true, false, and null.

When I attempt to evaluate `(x is true)`, I get a `Not implemented` error message. Attempting to evaluate `(x = true)` works just fine though.

```
dataeng=# with bool_vals as (select distinct val::boolean as x from my_table) select * from bool_vals;
 x
---
 f

 t
(3 rows)

dataeng=# with bool_vals as (select distinct val::boolean as x from my_table) select *, (x is null) from bool_vals;
 x | ?column?
---+----------
 f | f
 t | f
   | t
(3 rows)

dataeng=# with bool_vals as (select distinct val::boolean as x from my_table) select *, (x is true) from bool_vals;
ERROR:  Not implemented
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Not implemented
  code:      1001
  context:   'false' - project naming - 330
  query:     114596
  location:  cg_main.cpp:1265
  process:   padbmaster [pid=7556]
  -----------------------------------------------

dataeng=# with bool_vals as (select distinct val::boolean as x from my_table) select *, (x = true) from bool_vals;
 x | ?column?
---+----------
 t | t
 f | f
   |
(3 rows)
```

Oddly enough, I can't reproduce it using a trivial sample case:

```
dataeng=# with bools as (select true as x union select false union select null) select *, (x is true) from bools;
 x | ?column?
---+----------
 f | f
 t | t
   | f
(3 rows)
```

I'm fine with using `=` as an operator to evaluate boolean logic, but it seems odd that this behavior is inconsistent, and would like to clear up what is going on here.

Comment: `is true` doesn't seem like SQL to me.

Comment: I agree. I've never seen that syntax in SQL (but admittedly it might be in some other SQL databases).

Comment: Coming from a largely postgres world (which redshift is built from), where it works and is valid: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-comparison.html

Comment: Added a note and a new example to clarify this in our documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Redshift, the `IS {TRUE|FALSE|UNKNOWN}` syntax is not supported in the `SELECT` part of the query. It is *only* supported as a `WHERE` predicate.

We added a note and a new example to clarify this in our documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Boolean_type.html